# MetaMask Layer 1 Blockchain branding

Tags: blockchain, metamask

We have created a layer-one protocol and are able to connect it to MetaMask via RPC, ChainId...etc. How are we able to add our own branding to MetaMask the same way other blockchains like ETH do? I have attached a photo below outlining the branding example of ETH.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Metamask provides [`wallet_addEthereumChain`](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html#wallet-addethereumchain). That follows [EIP 3085](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-3085) which has a field `iconUrls` to provide images.

Currently it isn't used by Metamask. There's an open issue https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/15707.

```
iconUrls?: string[]; // Currently ignored.
```